# Is it possible to add a custom language to windows 10 using a font I have installed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, language

So this is a bit of an odd question, and potentially adding a custom language is not the best way to go about it. So please suggest any alternatives otherwise.

But I have installed a runic font, of which I also have these runic legends on my keyboard, but I would like to sometimes swap languages from English to type in this runic font conveniently, and was wondering if it would be possible to, in effect, swap the default font of my pc to use this runic script instead, without having to manually set the font in the personalisation settings.

I know that you can swap languages on the pc and type in those instead by adding a preferred language. But this script/language does not exist on the default options in the time and language settings.

So I was wondering if it is possible to add a custom language to these options and have it set to use my font. Or if this is not feasible, or even the best option, how else do you recommend I could go about doing this?

Comment: [0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134)
[1](https://keyman.com/keyboards/basic_kbdfthrk)
[2](https://www.heathenbydesign.com/rune-keyboard)
[3](https://keyman.com/keyboards/runeboard?bcp47=fo-runr)
[4](https://napkforpc.com/apk/net.blackenvelope.writeinrunic/)
[5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdfthrk)
[7](http://virtualkeyboard.biz/country/ancient)
[8](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Runic)
[9](https://www.reddit.com/r/runes/comments/nejzjw/does_anyone_know_if_there_is_a_runic_font_to/)

Comment: A default font for the PC doesn't exist - you only have a default font per application, and this usually doesn't depend on the language or the keyboard layout. Please specify the application (Word etc) in which you would like to select a default font per the current language or keyboard layout.